# OVH : Cloud Web and Gitlab-CI

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ovh

I'm used to Gitlab, and now I want to start deploying with Gitlab-CI, directly on the server. I've an OVH Cloud Web 1 account.

Currently, I made it work with this code in the .gitlab-ci.yml file and according vars in Gitlab :

```
stages:
    - deploy

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    image: ubuntu:latest
    environment:
        name: production
    only:
        - master
    before_script:
        - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
        - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
        - export SSHPASS=$DEPLOY_PASSWORD
    script:
        - sshpass -e ssh -tt -p $DEPLOY_PORT $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST git pull
```

I feel like this bit of code isn't clean, nor secured. Can you give me some advices ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be migrated to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @phd in such a case please see [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) and [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ "*Answers can suggest any improvement*" The Q is exactly for CodeReview.

Comment: @phd I agree that it can likely be on-topic there but please don't use that as a reason to vote to close. Please use a reason like *Needs More Focus* (like I have done), *Opinion based*, etc. Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Tnx, I'll consider this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When the scripts in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file become big and complicated, consider putting the code in separate scripts files instead. It is much easier to test and maintain a normal script then trying to do so inside of `.gitlab-ci.yml`. A good way to split it is into what should be done and how it is done. You put the `what` in `.gitlab-ci.yml` and the `how` into normal script files. For you it might be a file like `set-up-ssh.sh` that would do most of what you show in your example script.

When it comes to security, you already seem to be using GitLab's environments. This is the way to go to handle secure deployment with GitLab, and you can [limit the environment scopes of environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#limiting-environment-scopes-of-environment-variables). Also make sure that your command line tools read secrets from files and that nothing is passed through the shell. This could be stored in log files for your jobs, and you don't want your secrets to show there.